# Corona SDK (Lua) Sprite Sheet Animations

Tags: animation, lua, sprite, coronasdk

Im trying to get a sprite sheet to run through the 4 images so it plays an animation, although Corona SDK is giving me an error saying

"main.lua40: bad argument #2 to 'newImageSheet' (table (options)expected)
   stack traceback: [C]: in function 'newImageSheet' main.lua 40: in main chunk"

```
exclamationMarkAnimations = graphics.newImageSheet("exclamationMarkAnimated.png", sheetOptions)

exclamationMarkAnimated =
{
    width = 12,
    height = 12,
    numFrames = 4
}

animation = {
  {
    name = "bobbing",
    start = 1,
    count = 4,
    time = 800,
    loopCount = 0, -- "0" means always
    loopDirection = "forward"
   }
}

exclamationMarkVars = display.newSprite(exclamationMarkAnimations, exclamationMarkAnimated)

exclamationMarkVars:addEventListener("sprite", spriteListener)
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Whitch line is **line 40** ?

Comment: The very top line is line 40, thanks

Comment: Where is `sheetOptions` defined?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.

I followed the steps here https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/media/spriteAnimation/index.html
It isnt referred to anywhere else so im not sure

Answer (score 0):

That project is saved under Corona samples as you can see in the picture below:
and also in this folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Corona Labs\Corona SDK\Sample Code\Animation

You can use that as the base so save you some time.
[image]

Comment: No worries,  Can you please press the check as acceptable answer? Thanks